# Как установить pip в установленный python

Tags: python

Подскажите как установить pip в уже установленный python?
python 3.2.5, Windows 10, get-pip.py v3.2,
python get-pip.py выдает ошибку на строке:

```
    # Run the bootstrap
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
```

Полностью:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 17574, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 119, in bootstrap
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "C:\ProgramData\ASCON\KOMPAS-3D\19\Python 3\App\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
  File "C:\ProgramData\ASCON\KOMPAS-3D\19\Python 3\App\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extension.py", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
  File "C:\ProgramData\ASCON\KOMPAS-3D\19\Python 3\App\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 103
    except ValueError, e:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Comment: Добавьте полную трассу ошибки

Comment: попробуйте [отсюда скачать установщик](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/get-pip/main/public/3.2/get-pip.py) и запустить его

Comment: @Twiss, Так вроде оттуда и скачивал...

Comment: @Twiss, ничего не изменилось, та же ошибка.... может там еще не установлен модуль setuptools? как его установить?

Comment: Судя по синтаксису except, установленный модуль setuptools предназначен для версии Python 2, а не 3. Вы его как-то специально устанавливали, или он появился после запуска get-pip?

Comment: нет не устанавливал.

Comment: Попробуйте забэкапить папку с Python, удалить папку этого модуля и запустить get-pip еще раз

Answer (score 0):

сделайте `pip install pip` или обновновите `pip`

Comment: на этом питоне не установлен pip, соответственно данная команда не пройдет.